# Find $N$ with $N^2=10^4M+N$

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

I'm a high school student in France and I participated in a math olympiad, and there was a question which I found impossible to solve. Maybe they are here some people who can help me:

> We take a number $N$ which can be written by numbers $a,b,c$ and $d$ in
>   the same order.
>
> so $N=a(10^3)+b(10^2)+c10+d$. And $M\in \mathbb{Z}$ with
>   $N^2=M(10^4)+N$
>
> Find $M$.

Comment: "entire" en francais est "integer" en anglais :)

Comment: It looks like one trivial solution is $N=1,M=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parce que $N^2=10000M+N$, on saurait que le fin (4 digits) de $N^2$ et $N$ sont pareil.

Donc, le juste fin de $N$ serait $5$ ou $6$ ($5^2=25$, $6^2=36$).

On essaie et trouve que le fin serait $25$ ou $76$.

On essaie et trouve que le fin serait $625$ ou $376$ (on doit apprendre ca par coeur).

On essaie encore et trouve que $N$ serait seulement $9376$.

$9376^2=87909376$.

Comment: Why can you early reject the ends in $0$ or $1$ ?

Comment: tres bonne technique de resolution ( étant la plus facile) mais elle sembre marché que si  0<M<10 et rien dit que c'est cela non?

Comment: Ce méthode est pour ceux avec un "sense" des nombres. Pour un math olympiad, je vous suggèrerais de apprendre cela par coeur.

Comment: merci pour cette méthode mais ma question est si M est un tres grand nombre la méthode ne marche plus n'est-ce pas?

Comment: Oui. Mais, tu peux lire [cela](http://www.numericana.com/answer/p-adic.htm#decimal). Le 3ème nombre ($ ...62166509580863811000557423423230896109004106619977392256259918212890625$) est en fait le développement décimal de $\frac1{2^n}$. $1$ moins cela font $...37833490419136188999442576576769103890995893380022607743740081787109376$.

Answer (score 3):

$$10^4M=N^2-N=N(N-1)$$
Observe that $10^4$ divides $N(N-1)$ and $10^4>N\ge10^3$ as $N$ only has four digits. As their difference is 1, $N$ and $N-1$ are relatively prime to each other, meaning they don't have common divisors except $1$.

There are four cases

i) $10^4|N$, this cannot happen as $N$ is less than $10^4$.

ii) $2^4|N$ and $5^4|N-1$. Then, $N=k\cdot 5^4+1$ for some $k$. As $N$
has four digits, $2\le k\le 15$. $$5^4\equiv 1 \pmod{16}$$
So, $2^4=16|N$ implies $k=15, N=9376,M=8790$

iii) $5^4|N$ and $2^4|N-1$ Then, $N=k\cdot 5^4$ for some $k$. As $N$
has four digits, $2\le k\le 15$. $$5^4\equiv 1 \pmod{16}$$
So, $2^4=16|N-1$ implies $16|k-1$. However, no integer between $2$ and $15$ is equivelant to $1$ modulo $16$. Contradiction

iv) $10^4|N-1$, this cannot happen as $N-1$ is less than $10^4$.

Comment: but i thing they are many numbers N wih another M. Because M is a positive intege, so they are 8999 (9999-1000) possibility of N and M

Comment: The point you are missing is not every value of $M$ gives an $N$. For there to be a solution $N$, $M$ needs to be 8790, as proven above.

Answer (score 1):

$$N^2-N=10^4 \cdot M$$
$$N(N-1)=2^4\cdot 5^4\cdot M$$
$N(N-1)=16\cdot 625\cdot M$

$\gcd(N,N-1)=1$

Then 1)$$N=2^4k; N-1=5^4l, k,l \in \mathbb N$$ or 2)$$N-1=2^4k; N=5^4l, k,l \in \mathbb N$$

1) $10^4\le N-1=5^4l \le 10^5 \Rightarrow 2\le l \le 15$ and $16|N$

2)$10^4\le N=5^4l \le 10^5 \Rightarrow 2\le l \le 15$ and $16|(N-1)$

1) $l=2, N-1=1250$, but $16 \not |N=1251$

$l=3, N-1=1875$, but $16 \not |N=1876$

and so on ...

$l=15, N-1=9375, N=9376=586 \cdot 16$

$$N^2=9376^2=87909376=10^4\cdot 8790+9376$$
$$M=8790$$

Comment: http://oeis.org/A016090, http://oeis.org/A007185

Comment: http://www.numericana.com/answer/p-adic.htm#decimal

Comment: The two 10-adic integers sum up to 1 :o

Comment: but i thing they are many numbers N wih another M. Because M is a positive intege, so they are 8999 (9999-1000) possibility of N and M

Answer (score 1):

**By trial and error**.

The last digit of $N^2$ only depends on the last digit of $N$. We have the compatibilities

$$0\to0,1\to1,5\to5,6\to6.$$

With the last two digits, starting from these four solutions and trying to prefix all digits,

$$00\to00,
01\to01,
25\to25,
76\to76.$$

With the last three digits,

$$000\to000,
001\to001,
625\to625,
376\to376.$$

And with the four digits,

$$0000\to0000,
0001\to0001,
0625\to0625,
9376\to9376.$$

Note that this is a little better than brute force (trying all $10000$ possibilities), but it requires the evaluation of $10$ squares to add a digit, for a total of $130$ squares (!)

Comment: but i thing they are many numbers N wih another M. Because M is a positive intege, so they are 8999 (9999-1000) possibility of N and M

Comment: @MaickelTawdrous: can you please show me a single acceptable value of $N$ that I didn't list ? The question is about $N$, the value of $M$ is irrelevant.